# how do return myBlock?

Tags: product, magento2, extensions, cache, sorting

I have Block extend controller Product_view.
this block show

```
<ul>
   <li>Name</li>
   <li>Age</li>
   <li>Sex</li>
</ul>
```

I have selected option Sort By name, age, sex.

I sort by with jquery ajax. When change select option will post to MyBlock. but it `not run myBlock`. when I `refress cache` after change select option then `it run MyBlock`. So how does it work not need refresh cache it works? I think the same sort of the product list, but I don't understand method Sorter in the product.

Comment: can you share your block code?

Comment: I Edited question @Abdul